# For which primes $p$ is $-3\in Q_p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues, quadratic-reciprocity

I'm really bad at doing these for some reason, just need some help, this is not a hw question. I just need to do these smaller problems to gain some understanding.

For which primes $p$ is $-3\in Q_p$ (quadratic residues of p)?

I know that $(\frac{-3}{p})=(\frac{-1}{p})(\frac{3}{p})$

For $(\frac{-1}{p})$ = 1 if $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ and -1 if $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$

Also for $(\frac{-3}{p})$ = 1 if $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod{12}$ and -1 if $p\equiv \pm 5\pmod{12}$

If I CRT these it's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that $p>3$. Then by quadratic reciprocity,
$$ \Big(\frac{3}{p}\Big)=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}\frac{3-1}{2}}\Big(\frac{p}{3}\Big)=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\Big(\frac{p}{3}\Big)$$
Since
$$ \Big(\frac{-1}{p}\Big)=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$$
it follows that
$$ \Big(\frac{-3}{p}\Big)=\Big(\frac{-1}{p}\Big)\Big(\frac{3}{p}\Big)=\Big(\frac{p}{3}\Big)$$
which is $1$ when $p\equiv 1$ (mod $3$) and is $-1$ when $p\equiv -1$ (mod $3$).

Comment: So we don't have to worry about cases where $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ or $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$?

Comment: No, because the term $(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ conveniently cancels out.

Comment: I think I understand now. Since $(\frac{-3}{p})=((-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}})((-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}})(\frac{p}{3})=(\frac{p}{3})$. The signs will cancel.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more elegant proof without quadratic reciprocity. Suppose, $-3$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, i.e. there exists an $x$ such that
$$
x^2 \equiv -3 \pmod{p}.
$$
Let, $x =2y+1$ (note that $\frac{x-1}{2}$ is a well-defined quantity modulo $p$). We have,
$$
4y^2+4y+4\equiv 0 \pmod{p}\implies p\mid (y^2+y+1)\implies p\mid y^3 - 1.
$$
Let $d$ be the smallest positive integer for which $y^d\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Clearly, $d\mid p-1$. Also, $d\mid 3$. We know that $d$ can't be $1$ (otherwise, $p$ would be $3$), hence, $d = 3$. Therefore,
$$
3|p-1 \implies p\equiv 1\pmod{3}.
$$

Comment: Thanks I always like to see different ways to do problems.

Comment: Could you explain why $p$ would be $3$ if $d$ were $1\;$?